# Build/visualize a tree from rules

Tags: r

I have if/then statements that describe a tree.  For example:

```
node1: if VAR1 < X node = 2 else node = 3
node2: if VAR2 < Y node = 4 else node = 5
node3: terminal value = Z
...
```

The inequalities are always expressed as less than "<".  The rules are not necessarily in order of tree depth.

Ignoring the work to parse the statements, what's the easiest way to build/visualize a tree in R?  Is there an object/function/package I can call once per rule to iteratively build-up the tree and then call plot()?

Comment: Have you looked at the party package?

Comment: Not yet..thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I do not think you can derive a unique tree without some ordering of the rules.

Comment: @DWin - I don't think ordering matters.  Each line specifies a node and if not a terminal node then it specifies its left and right child.  You can imagine randomizing the lines and then drawing each node/connection in the order it appears in the randomized list.  The same tree would result regardless of order (although it would look pretty ugly)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from the comment I gave earlier, this is the top of the example of `plot.BinaryTree` in the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/package=party) package:

```
   set.seed(290875)

   airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
   airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)

   ### regression: boxplots in each node
   plot(airct, terminal_panel = node_boxplot, drop_terminal = TRUE)
```

and it generates the following graph based on the `ctree` command above:

[image]

The package has two pretty decent vignettes which should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I tried digging down into the code for pkg:party methods but could not follow the dependencies very effectively. I thought looking at the rpart package code might be easier. (Edit: Further thought would be to look at the igraph package.)

```
require(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
print(fit)
#------------
n= 81 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 81 17 absent (0.79012346 0.20987654)  
   2) Start>=8.5 62  6 absent (0.90322581 0.09677419)  
     4) Start>=14.5 29  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
     5) Start< 14.5 33  6 absent (0.81818182 0.18181818)  
      10) Age< 55 12  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
      11) Age>=55 21  6 absent (0.71428571 0.28571429)  
        22) Age>=111 14  2 absent (0.85714286 0.14285714) *
        23) Age< 111 7  3 present (0.42857143 0.57142857) *
   3) Start< 8.5 19  8 present (0.42105263 0.57894737) *
#---code resumes ------
plot(fit)
```

[image]

```
rpart:::plot.rpart   # will show the code  ... depends on rpart::rpconvert
rpart::rpconvert
```

Comment: thanks!  I had the same idea to deconstruct what rpart does, but thought there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the data.tree package. You could for example do:

```
tree <- Node$new("node1")
tree$AddChild("node2", edgeLabel = "VAR1 < X")
tree$AddChild("node3", edgeLabel = "VAR1 >= X")

print(tree, "edgeLabel")
```

This would show as:

```
  levelName  edgeLabel
1 node1              
2  ¦--node2   VAR1 < X
3  °--node3  VAR1 >= X
```

Or plotting:

```
SetEdgeStyle(tree, label = function(node) node$edgeLabel)
plot(tree)
```

[image: Nodes]

Each node can store any information, so parsing that would also be straight forward, because you can use the tree as a router while parsing.